# c++ Dereferecing Pointers assigned by pass-by-reference giving random values

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

I have an array of pointers that are supposed to hold the memory location of other Objects. Adding the arrays to list2 and printing out a value from that Object gives me the right value. But doing trying to print it from another function gives me random values instead.

Classes:

```
class Airline() {
Airline();
Flight *list2[20]; //array of pointers to Flight
};

class Flight() {
int flightNo;
int MaxPeople;
};
```

Add Flight function:

```
currentPos1 =-1     //Global Variable

void Airline::addFlight(Flight flight) {
currentPos1++;
list2[currentPos1] = &flight;
cout <<(*list2[currentPos1]).flightNo <<"\n"; //Gives proper Value
}
```

ShowAllFlights function:

```
void AirDB::showAllFlights() {
  for (int i = 0; i <= currentPos1; i++)
    {
     //Both cout's provide random values;
      cout <<"\nFlight Number: " <<list2[i]->flightNo;
      cout <<"\nMaxPeople: " << list2[i]->maxPeople;
     }
}
```

Is my referencing and de-referencing wrong here?
Any help would be very Appreciated.

Comment: The comment `//array of pointers to pointers` should read `array of pointers to Flight`. A flight is not a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue is here:

`list2[currentPos1] = &flight;`

That will not work, as you're assigning a pointer to a temporary `Flight`.  When the `addFlight` function returns, that pointer is no longer valid.

What you want to do is pass the `Flight` by reference (preferably a `const` reference):

```
void Airline::addFlight(const Flight& flight)
```

Note that this is predicated on the lifetime of the argument you're sending to `addFlight`.  For this particular function, `flight` will be valid, but after the function call, the argument you're sending also has to be valid for the lifetime you intend on using that pointer you've stored in `list2`.

Instead of array of pointers to `Flight`, using `std::vector<Flight>` would be an easier solution.

Comment: This probably won't solve the problem as the calling argument probably will end its lifetime soon after

Comment: Thankyou. That's exactly what I was missing.